# How can I stop Hibernate's SQLExceptionConverter from converting error messages stored in a SQL Server procedure?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

The issue is that I am calling a stored procedure from my java code and when I do so, it does not return the expected error messages which I specify in the procedure itself.
The error I'm getting is an SQLGrammarException which, based on debugging results, occurs from Hibernate's SQLExceptionConverter.
Is there some way in which I can set the number of delegates to 0? That was it would emit the original error message if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options that I've come across for your need, based on the ease of implementation you could choose the best-suited option for yourself.

*Option-1:*

You can implement your own SQLExceptionConverter to define what needs to be passed as is and what needs to be wrapped before sending to your business logic layer. Take a look at this [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/exception/SQLExceptionConverter.html).

*Option-2:*

Have a look at [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), which is a reference implementation of JSR-303. You can do good amount of validation yourself, even before you put your entities into the Database.

Hope this helps!!!